Using XmlWriter changing the the Declaration
Right now Im making a XML file but it seems when I create the XML file I get this declaretions   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> Im trying to setup <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> How can I do this in XmlWriter? Right now I only found a hard coded way and Im trying to avoid the practice of this type of code writer.WriteRaw("<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?>"); Any idea would be great Im new to using XmlWriter
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = "Test.xml";

        // Create an instance of XmlWriter with the specified settings
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filePath)
        {
            
            // Write your XML content here
            writer.WriteStartElement("Root");
            writer.WriteElementString("Element", "Value");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("XML has been created successfully.");
    }


Use WriteStartDocument(true)

Thanks Alexander! is there away to remove encoding="utf-8"?

Does this answer your question? Remove encoding from XmlWriter

Does this answer your question? remove encoding from xmlserializer
